# Why i3 doesn't read its config files (they exist) and starts with defaults?

Tags: x11, i3

I've encrypted partition with 'cryptsetup'.
All operations inside of virtual consoles work properly.

Comment: it seems like you've answered your question, because the partition is encrypted and i3 can't open the config file when it loads. You might want to poke a bit more at this question and see when i3 exactly loads its configs in the i3 start process. Vs when you put in the decryption login or whatever happens there. And which user i3 config handler is when it reads the config file. There may be special i3 directives needed for this scenario, if it's supported. Once logged in, if you do special key + reload default key, I think it's r, does it still load defaults?

Comment: Thanks but my home partition is not encrypted. And it is mounted as usually. Read and execute permissions are correct, I checked them first.

Comment: work on providing meaningful data when you ask a question, read what you wrote, you didn't include any actual relevant information.

Comment: I just was uninformed about partition encryption (gpt, ext4, luks) and file management basic specifics. There are no rules with basical usage of the file system after input of correct passphrase to the /dev/mapper`s mounted encrypted device. The question was that. (I would appreciate comments providing any links to services structurally resolving such basic issues, if Unix-SE doesn't oriented on the basics).

Comment: You are telling us that All operations inside of virtual consoles work properly.What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `i3 -C` or `i3 -c <file>` reports?

```
    -c <file>   use the provided configfile instead
    -C          validate configuration file and exit
    -d all      enable debug output
```

By default it should be `$HOME/.config/i3/config`.

Comment: Probably it is missing of Terminus TTF font file for dmenu inside of i3 config. I forget to copy it from X-configured machine to this new install. (I will check this assumption after my day work and your debug params and close the question)